# How to parse following JSOn DATA

Tags: android, json

```
[
  {
    "ORDERID": [
      "Epp144534354354",
      "Epp14453sdfgsfd",
      "Epp14487484",
      "Epp144454464646"
    ],
    "ADDRESS": " MUMBAI",
    "FOLLOW_UPDATE": "25/5/2017",
    "SIGN_IMAGE": "sign.png",
    "DATE_TIME": "2017-05-02 17:52:09.0",
    "EMAIL": "abhi@abhi.con",
    "IMAGE_1": "image1.jpg",
    "COMMENT": "gshshshsh",
    "IMAGE_3": "image3.jpg",
    "NAME": "abhi",
    "MOBILE": "22416545",
    "IMAGE_2": "image2.jpg"
  }
]
```

I want to parse above json data then how to parse the json in android how to parse code in java

Comment: please format your json block. Its a mesh now. And remove empty lines.

Comment: Can you show us your current effort? Have you tried something that leads to accomplishing your goal? Perhaps JsonReader, GSON, Jackson or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.Here is JSON parsing in android.

```
 String response=" [\n" +
            "{ \"ORDERID\": [ \"Epp144534354354\", \"Epp14453sdfgsfd\", \"Epp14487484\", \"Epp144454464646\"],\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"ADDRESS\": \" 26, Wakad Road Samarth Colony, Omkar Society, Pimple Nilakh Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra 411027\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"FOLLOW_UPDATE\": \"25/5/2017\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"SIGN_IMAGE\": \"http://192.168.0.108:8084/MarketingApplicationImages/IMAGES//sign.png\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"DATE_TIME\": \"2017-05-02 17:52:09.0\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"EMAIL\": \"abhi@abhi.con\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"IMAGE_1\": \"http://192.168.0.108:8084/MarketingApplicationImages/IMAGES//image1.jpg\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"COMMENT\": \"gshshshsh\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"IMAGE_3\": \"http://192.168.0.108:8084/MarketingApplicationImages/IMAGES//image3.jpg\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"NAME\": \"abhi\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"MOBILE\": \"8149608493\",\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"IMAGE_2\": \"http://192.168.0.108:8084/MarketingApplicationImages/IMAGES//image2.jpg\"\n" +
            "  }]";

    try {
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i <jArray.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jonj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray orderArray=jonj.getJSONArray("ORDERID");
            for (int j = 0; j <orderArray.length(); j++) {

                Log.e("array value"," .....   "+orderArray.getString(i));

            }
            Log.e("address"," .....   "+jonj.getString("ADDRESS"));
            Log.e("FOLLOW_UPDATE"," .....   "+jonj.getString("FOLLOW_UPDATE"));
            Log.e("SIGN_IMAGE"," .....   "+jonj.getString("SIGN_IMAGE"));

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse json please follow this basic rules which will help you in long run.

1. First check if json is valid or not, [paste your json response and click validate json.](https://jsonlint.com/)
2. To view json content in proper format to understand better use [paste your data in text section and switch to view section to view it.](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)
3. Then use GSON library to parse the data(refer any online tutorial)
4. You would require pojo's for GSON use [paste json response in the text box section which is located on the left hand side and then on the right hand side set source type as JSON annotation type as GSON and click on the preview at the bottom of the page, copy it and use it.](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)